# Not able to run java 11 sample program in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

```
public class First {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello Java 11");
  }
}
```

I am trying to run above program in Java 11 with intellij. But getting below Error.

```
Information:javac 11 was used to compile java sources
Information:Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format, forcing project rebuild: Module 'eleven-lab' production: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jrt
Information:25/09/18, 6:58 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 4s 516ms
Error:Internal error: (java.net.MalformedURLException) unknown protocol: jrt
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jrt
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:421)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:310)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:333)
    at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder.createJDKPlatformUrl(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.instrumentation.ClassProcessingBuilder.createInstrumentationClassFinder(ClassProcessingBuilder.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.instrumentation.ClassProcessingBuilder.build(ClassProcessingBuilder.java:93)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1246)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:995)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:719)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:371)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

java: **openjdk-11+28_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz**

os: **macOS 10.13.2**

intellij: **ideaIC-2018.2.4**

Comment: I assume you have cleared your intellij caches. I have tried the Oracle install without a problem *on Linux*. Uninstalling the openjdk and installing it again might help.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanx! It worked after clearing the intellij caches.

Comment: @shubham12511 Can you write that as an answer and accept it (when possible)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java 11 is still very new.

I suspect IntelliJ's caches got corrupted and clearing them should help.

I would also keep Intellij up to date if using such a new JDK.

Comment: Can you suggest how to clear those possibly corrupted caches?

Comment: I updated Intellij from 2017 to 2018.2.4 and issue was gone.

Answer (score 6):

Same error here, upgraded to intellij 2018.1 and the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Open "Registry..." (double-press `shift` and type `Registry`). If `compiler.process.jdk` is *not* at default, reset the registry to defaults.